# Numerical bottlenecks

Tags: computational-physics, hardware

On a desktop scale computer, what are the most important bottlenecks (RAM vs. CPU, single vs. multithread) for numerical calculations? I'm specifically most interested in exact diagonalization and other methods (DMRG, DMFT) for strongly-correlated condensed matter systems. What computational resources would pose the strongest limitations?

Context: my advisor is planning on buying a new desktop/workstation using grant money. We have access to a cluster, so this would be used for testing code on intermediate scales before adjusting it to take advantage of the cluster.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of specifications to consider when buying a desktop computer to use for scientific computing.  In each of these areas, there's a minimum that will be necessary to get your work done and more or less opportunity to get improved performance at a higher cost.  You should consider all of these issues, but the answers will be specific to your particular project.

1. Operating system.  Are you going to run Linux, Windows, or Mac OS as your operating system?  Are you going to use a virtual machine or dual boot setup to run multiple operating systems?  What OS do you prefer to use?  What OS do you have to use because of particular software that only runs in one environment?
2. Open source and licensed software.  What software do you want to run on your computer?  Are there particular open source or licensed commercial software packages that you want to run?
3. Disk space.  How much disk space do you need?  For a typical desktop machine with a single user, a common 2 TB hard drive might be perfectly adequate.  However, if you handle very large data sets, you might need much more disk space for your data sets.  A RAID setup can provide increased reliability and performance if you've got a lot of data.
4. Disk performance.  If your code does a lot of I/O to disk, then the read/write speed of your hard disk can be very important.  On a day-to-day basis, the speed of the disk that holds your operating system can have a big impact on performance.  Your options here range from Solid State Drives (SSD) that are fast but limited in size and expensive per byte to disk drives that are slower but are the most economical choice.  Using an SSD for the operating system and a conventional hard disk for your data is often a good compromise.
5. Memory (RAM) space.  Depending on the size of your data sets, your code may need very little memory or it may need a very large amount of RAM.  You should make sure that you have enough RAM for the largest problems you want to solve.
6. Memory (RAM) speed.  There isn't a large range of speed in RAM sold for desktop computers and you probably won't get to choose this.
7. Memory (RAM) channels and slots.  The memory subsystem of your computer can have 1, 2, 4, 6, or even 8 memory channels, each of which might have 1, 2, or more RAM modules installed.  For example, the computer I'm using has 4 memory channels with two DIMM slots per channel.  I've got one 8 GB DIMM on each channel for a total of 32 GB of RAM.  The available memory bandwidth increases proportionally to  the number of channels that are actually in use, so you want to have at least as many DIMM's as you have memory channels.  I could have saved money by buying two 16 GB DIMMS, but the performance would have been worse.
8. Number of CPU cores.  You can spend a lot of money on a processor with as many as 30 processor cores, but practically it's often hard to take advantage of multiple cores, especially because there's often not sufficient memory bandwidth to keep the cores busy.
9. Speed of the CPU cores.  Often single-threaded parts of your code will end up being bottlenecks.  A smaller number of faster cores will often out-perform a larger number of slower cores on such workloads.  If you're not sure how well your code runs on many cores, then you might want to go for a processor with the fastest cores you can afford even though there will be fewer of them.
10. GPU for graphics.  If you do a significant amount of visualization of computational results, you might need a high-performance GPU to support these graphics.
11. GPGPU for computing.  A high-performance GPU can also be used for numerical computing.  If you have software that has been optimized for use with a GPU, or if you're willing to invest a considerable amount of effort in getting your code to take advantage of a GPU, then you might consider buying a GPU for computing.

Note that NVIDIA's less expensive GPU's have limited double-precision floating point performance- if you need double precision, then you really want one of the more expensive Tesla models.  AMD/Radeon GPU's are also an option, but there's much less software support for them.